# Want to count characters from cmd argument array

Tags: java, arrays, string, count, args

I'm quite new to java.
I have studied my code for a long time and I just can't find a good way to declare the args array in a simple string I can count _length();

I am getting the args array by doing the following in cmd: `java Sentence this is a good day to die`.
The output is the way i want it atm, but, how do I efficiently count an args array for characters? My way of declaring every single `args[0], args[1]`, etc doesn't feel right.

Right now this is my code:

```
public class Sentence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        String t = args[1];
        String a = args[2];
        String r = args[3];
        String l = args[4];
        int sum = s.length()+t.length()+a.length()+r.length()+l.length();

        System.out.print("You wrote: ");

        for (int j=0; j < args.length; j++){
            System.out.print(" "+args[j]);
        }

        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("\nNumber of Words:\t"+args.length);
            System.out.println("Number of characters:\t"+sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`args` is an array. You should iterate over it :

```
int sum=0;
for (String s : args) {
    sum+=s.length();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
      int count =0;
       for (String string : args) {
          count += string.length()  
    }
       System.out.println(count);
}
```

Loop on you args and add the each strings length to `count` variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
String s = args[0];
String t = args[1];
String a = args[2];
```

You can't predetermine the length of the sentence. Java handles that argument array for you. What you should do is iterate through that array and get the length of each argument length and added them together.
So code would looks like

```
int sum = 0
for(String arg : args)
   sum += arg.length();
```